# Grid of multiple entities of different types

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way in MS Dynamics 2013 for creating a grid that accepts multiple entities of different types? For example: I want to create a new instance of entyty X. In the form I have a grid in which I can add systemusers and teams.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

it's not possible to create a grid that will show different entities

Comment: Ok but is there a workaround that can do the purpose?

Comment: create two relationships to hold the data and after create an HTML webresource that will display the data inside a grid

Comment: But I think that, doing the web resource, it'is not possible to add items. Am I right?

Comment: you can implement your own add button. This takes development, it's not just a couple of hours thing